# Find $\frac{dG}{dx} |_{x=1}$ for given function $G(x)$

Tags: calculus

> We have $G(x) = \frac{(1-x)(1-\rho)L_B (\lambda (1-x))}{L_B (\lambda (1-x)) -x}$, where $L_B (\lambda (1-x))$ is the Laplace transform of $B$.
>
> $\rho$ and $\lambda$ are parameters.
>
> I want to show that $\frac{dG}{dx} |_{x=1} = \rho + \frac{\lambda^2 E[B^2]}{2(1-\rho)}$.

Since $L_B (\lambda (1-x))$ is a Laplace transform, we have

$(\frac{d}{dx} L_B (\lambda (1-x))) |_{x=1} = E[B]$ and $ (\frac{d^2}{dx^2} L_B (\lambda (1-x))) |_{x=1} = E[B^2]$. Furthermore $L_B (0) = 1$.

Using the quotient rule I got:

$\displaystyle \frac{dG}{dx} |_{x=1} = \frac{(L_B (\lambda (1-x)) -x) \cdot [-(1-\rho)\cdot L_B (\lambda (1-x))-(1-x)\cdot (1-\rho)\cdot (\frac{d}{dx} L_B (\lambda (1-x)))] - (1-x)(1-\rho)L_B (\lambda (1-x))\cdot ((\frac{d}{dx} L_B (\lambda (1-x))) -1)}{[L_B (\lambda (1-x)) -x]^2} |_{x=1}$

$= \displaystyle  \frac{(L_B (0) -1) \cdot [-(1-\rho)\cdot L_B (0)] }{[L_B (0) -1]^2}$

But this does not look like $\rho + \frac{\lambda^2 E[B^2]}{2(1-\rho)}$ at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in the formula you wrote. $ (1-\rho) $ is a simple factor of the all function and does not correspond with what you are supposed to show. ie $\rho + ...$

Also, you need to add $ -\lambda $ when you take the derivative.

$$
\frac{d}{dx} (LB(λ(1−x)))_{|x=1} = -\lambda*E[B]  
$$

and

$$
\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}} (LB(λ(1−x)))_{|x=1} = \lambda^{2}*E[B^{2}]  
$$